Rebooting remote Linux device (Pi type device) from Windows by bat file
I have been trying to reboot the Linux board from Windows in the following way using C#. If I execute C# function by API nothing happens but if I execute the bat file by double-clicking, I see the device reboots. What could be the issue?
log.Info("Rebooting Pi " + ip );
string path = @"C:\data\rebootpi.bat";
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    w.WriteLine("@echo off");
    String s = string.Format("plink -batch root@{0} -pw secret_pass /sbin/reboot", ip);
    w.WriteLine(s);
    w.Close();
}

try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc2 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc2.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\data\";
    proc2.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\data\rebootpi.bat";
    bool b = proc2.Start();
    log.Info("Rebooting Pi  = " + b);
    proc2.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}


Hi @RotatingWheel, are you able to debug your implementation and see what happens? It is possible that some user permissions block your implementation from starting the batch file.

An empty catch block is usually the root of all evil.

You don't need a DOS batch file (Windows uses .cmd or .ps1). You can execute plink with arguments using Process.Start("plink.exe",$"-batch root@{ip} -pw secret_pass /sbin/reboot");, if plink is on the path. Otherwise you need to specify the full path to plink.exe

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos your comment is legitimate, but it should also work using the batch file.

@Codor Which adds one layer of complexity and an attack vector. Each of which would be enough to move away from it in my book.

I see the following output : Rebooting Pi 10.10.10.10
Rebooting Pi  = True    I don't get any exception there, nothing comes in the exception code, meaning I don't see any exception. I can debug step by step and it looks fine but the board does not reboot. If I click on the bat file (produced by the code), I see the board is rebooting.

@Codor no it won't. Process.Start only executes actual executable files. Batch files require a shell to process them. If UseShellExecute is set, the FileName argument is passed to the OS GUI Shell for processing through its registered app, which in .bat's case is cmd.exe, just as WinWord is the registered app for .docx. On .NET Core though, UseShellExecute is off by default.

"Rebooting Pi 10.10.10.10 Rebooting Pi = True" IP "10.10.10.10" ?? Looks suspicious.

What is suspicious? I did not get it.

Did you remove the catch{} to see the actual error? I bet it's saying that rebootpi.bat isn't an executable program. Are you using .NET Core? .NET 5 and later are actually .NET Core versions. Batch files aren't executable, they're documents that need to be run by a shell like cmd.exe. When UseShellExecute is true, Process.Start passes the file name to the Windows Shell (ie Explorer), which in turn processes it using its registered application like Word for .docx, cmd for .cmd or .bat and Powershell for .ps1. You can actually change the association of .bat

Why not just try the plink command from the command line.  When you get the syntax right then feed it into your C# program.

@cup, if I run the bat file generated by the command line or by double-clicking, it works fine. But if I execute via the C# code, nothing happens, no exception. But the board is not rebooted.

@PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the clarification above, I guess I was mistaken!

"What is suspicious? I did not get it." - It may not be. A uniform IPv4 in the 10.X.X.X space is somewhat poking into my eye. That's all. Nevermind - if it works for you.

You don't need an MS-DOS batch file. You're trying to use plink so Process should be used to start that program. In any case, in .NET Core you can't just use a document's path to run it with its registered application.
Assuming plink is in the PATH, you can use :
Process.Start("plink.exe",$"-batch root@{ip} -pw secret_pass /sbin/reboot");

or, to make things clearer:
string args=$"-batch root@{ip} -pw secret_pass /sbin/reboot";

var proc=Process.Start("plink.exe",args);
proc.WaitForExit();

Don't use catch{} to hide errors. In this case, it's possible to get an exception if plink.exe isn't on the path, in which case you need to either change the path or use the absolute path of the tool.
You can read plink's actual output using stdout or stderr redirection, eg :
  var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
      FileName = "plink.exe",
      Arguments=args,
      RedirectStandardError = true
  };  
  var p=Process.Start(pInfo);

  string output = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();  
  p.WaitForExit();

  Console.WriteLine($"\nError stream: {output}");


I get the following as output when called by C#: You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1040 SHA256:lR5hgAUOU6D07ahFdNnByRF5SrSIn8L1E79p+7ajZiI
Connection abandoned.
FATAL ERROR: Cannot confirm a host key in batch mode

There we go: you're calling plink, but it's returning an error

After doing more research, I found a working and better solution. The Library on this page (https://sshnet.github.io/SSH.NET/index.html) works for me. Also, it is very simple compared to my original sample. Thanks, everyone.
using (var client = new SshClient("10.10.25.100", "root", "secret_password"))
{
client.Connect();
SshCommand cmd = client.RunCommand("path to reboot command");
//Check cmd for possible failure
}

